# Passing a listbox as a function parameter in VBA gives me a Runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I must be missing something obvious but somehow im getting a type mismatch error.

```
Private Sub btnGenerate_Click()
    populateListBox "Table_Install_Base", 1, Me.lbPressType
end sub
Sub populateListBox(sTableName As String, iColumn As Integer, lb As ListBox)
    Dim v, e
    With Sheets(1).ListObjects(sTableName).ListColumns(iColumn).DataBodyRange
        v = .Value
    End With
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = 1
        For Each e In v
            If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then lb.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With
end sub
```

EDIT:

Removed sTableName and iColumn and hardcoded those values, keep getting the same error. So 100% sure it is related to the listbox. Don't know if it is of any help, but running this code from inside a userform in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your ListBox is an ActiveX ListBox.  If this is correct, you need to change the signature on your Sub as follows:

```
Sub populateListBox(sTableName As String, iColumn As Integer, lb As MSForms.ListBox)
```

Remember, there are 2 types of ListBox, ActiveX and Forms.  The ActiveX ListBox is declared as `MSForms.ListBox` whereas the Forms ListBox is declared as `ListBox`.